# how to make emulator for testing Nfc in android

Tags: android, nfc

I have downloaded OpenNFC Android SDK addon from http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-nfc/files/

its give some structure of folders ,please specify me how to install that add-ons on sdk.
i have to make Nfc enable emulator for testing Nfc.

folder contain following structure

```
Hierarchy 
├── Demo - ChangePolicy 
├── Kernel 
│ ├── kernel_for_AOSP 
│ │ └── nfc 
│ └── kernel_for_NFCRealDevice 
│ └── nfc 
├── libnfc-opennfc 
│ ├── java 
│ │ ├── jni 
│ │ └── src 
│ │ └── com 
│ │ └── opennfc 
│ │ └── extension 
│ │ └── nfc 
│ │ └── api 
│ ├── ndef 
│ ├── open_nfc 
│ │ ├── hardware 
│ │ │ └── libhardware 
│ │ │ ├── include 
│ │ │ │ └── hardware
```

Comment: http://open-nfc.org/wp/nfchal/simulator/requirements/

Answer (score 0):

//there are few Limitations in Android Emulator

The functional limitations of the emulator include:

```
No support for placing or receiving actual phone calls. You can simulate phone calls (placed and received) through the emulator console, however.
No support for USB connections
No support for device-attached headphones
No support for determining network connected state
No support for determining battery charge level and AC charging state
No support for determining SD card insert/eject
No support for Bluetooth
No Support for NFC adapter or NFC capabilities to run in emulator.
```

Comment: thanks for reply but my question is how to make emulator because i don't have device to test nfc related app.so i have read steps that is download nfc add-ons ,i have download add-ons but can't install it in android sdk